# Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'Slides' does not exist on 'Page'

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this. Here is my code:

```
class Page extends SiteTree
{
    private static $many_many = [
        'Slides' => SliderImage::class,
    ];

    private static $many_many_extraFields = [
        'Slides' => ['SlideSort' => 'Int'],
    ];

    private static $table_name = 'Page';

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Gallery',
            $grid = GridField::create(
                'Slides',
                'Slides',
                $this->Slides(),
                GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
                    ->addComponent(GridFieldOrderableRows::create('SlideSort'))
            )
        );
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

I get this error: `[Emergency] Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'Slides' does not exist on 'Page'`

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration cache is outdated. Add `?flush` to your web browser URL to clear it.

SilverStripe caches configuration in both the command line and the browser. If you're modifying a private static property (such as `$many_many` and `$many_many_extraFields` in this example) then you need to flush the configuration cache in order for it to be respected.

With a stale cache and a new ORM relationship you get this error, because SilverStripe doesn't know about the relationship in order to provide a magic method to access it (`$this->Slides()`).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. The code structure of *.yml files not well organized those errors can be occurs. for a example,

```
SilverStripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - SilverStripers\RC\Extensions\SiteConfigExtension
```

there is a space must be include before extensions: (above code)